# Angular 4 is not rendering my ID in my child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have 3 components, they are nested.
But the ID on the last child is not rendering using `id = {{myId}}`. 
I tried `[id]=myID` as well.

Something like this:
[image]

**GrandFather:**

```
<app-middle-section #middleSection
                    myTitle="Title" 
                    myID="my_id_creation" >
</app-middle-section>
```

**Father:**

```
<div class="section rounded"> 
    <div class="title">{{myTitle}}</div>
    <app-list #glist
                myID= {{myID}} 
    </app-list>
</div>
```

**Child**

```
<div class="">
    <div id="{{myID}}" class=""></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
If I use console log on the last component it prints my "my_id_creation". 
For the Father and Child I'm using the:

```
@Input() myID: string;
```

Comment: Your `app-list` is unclosing. Also, you are not showing `myID` in `app-list`. see fixed example https://plnkr.co/edit/96V3vie3BbqGDf6u8DoY?p=preview

Comment: @Pengyy if I try to show like you did, it worked. 
It shows, but the div below doesn't render the id.

Comment: please confirm again. I see the id been assigned to `my_id_creation` at the fixed sample.

Comment: @Pengyy Yes, it's rendering on Plnkr. I don't know what is happening. If I put the value directly it works.

Comment: Thank you, It's solved. It has more than one @input inside the component, I remove everything and set it again, so it's working right now, it could be some other typing error. The weird part is that I don't have any error in the console.

Comment: ok, you are welcome. glad to hear you have got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting an error? In any case, your father and child components need to define those id's as input, something along the lines of this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'father-component',
    template: `
        <div class="section rounded"> 
            <div class="title">{{myTitle}}</div>
            <app-list #glist
                [id]="id"
            </app-list>
        </div>
    `
})
export class FatherComponent {
    @Input() id: number;
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I Have been add the input inside father and child

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeReis That's odd, any form of databinding where the input has not been properly set up will result in an error, including when the entire component is unknown. Could you reproduce your situation in a Plnkr/jsfiddle somewhere?

Comment: I never use, i'm going to try.

Comment: thank you, It's solved. It has more than one @input inside the component, I remove everything and set it again, so it's working right now, it could be some other typing error. The weird part is that I don't have any error in the console

Comment: I found why, you're using `<app-list #glist myID="{{myID}}">`. If you were to use the more correct notation of property binding, `<app-list #glist [myID]="myID">`, then Angular will throw an error if that `myID` does not have an `@Input()` decorated on it. But hey, great news that it works, well done.